# How to zip and base64 an org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java, dom, base64, zip

I have a org.w3c.dom.Document and have to zip and base64 encode it to send it with the EBICS protocol via HTTP/HTTPS
I tried

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
    InputStream inflated_stream = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()));
    final byte[] bytes64bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(IOUtils.toByteArray(inflated_stream));
    OrderData = new String(bytes64bytes);
```

but get an exception

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1025)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:999)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:218)
```

Comment: I cannot use gzip as standard zip is the requested compression method in EBICS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but wouldn't the following do what you need?

`OutputStream outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());`

I think your problem might be down to the use of `InflaterInputStream` - aren't you trying to **deflate** this stream? You code may work if you just change `InflaterInputStream` to `DeflaterInputStream`

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
InputStream inflated_stream = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()));
```

to

```
InputStream inflated_stream = new DeflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()));
```

solved the issue
Thanks